# Multiple drop events in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to create a drag and drop feature in HTML5 where I can drag from one list to another.  I have one list with draggable items and another list with items that have drop events added. The problem is, regardless of what element I drop onto, the last drop event that was added is the one that gets called.

Thanks for any help or suggestions.

I've included my code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<title>List Conversion Test</title>

<style type="text/css">

#list, #cart {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #444;
  margin: 25px;
  padding: 10px;
}

#list p {
  background-color: #036;
  color: #fff;
}
#cart p {
  background-color: #363;
  color: #fff;
}

.listitem {

}

.listitem_done {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

.product {
  background-color: #CCC;
}

.product_over {
  background-color: #363;
}

</style>


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://html5demos.com/js/h5utils.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<article>
  <div id="list">
    <p>On My List</p>
    <ul>
      <li class="listitem" id="L001">Shopping List Item #1</li>
      <li class="listitem" id="L002">Shopping List Item #2</li>
    </ul>
    <div id="done">
      <p>In My Cart</p>
      <ul></ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="cart">
    <p>Cart</p>
    <ul>
      <li class="product" id="P001">Product #1</li>
      <li class="product" id="P002">Product #2</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</article>
<script>

  // make list items draggable
  var list = document.querySelectorAll('li.listitem'), thisItem = null;
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    thisItem = list[i];

    thisItem.setAttribute('draggable', 'true');

    addEvent(thisItem, 'dragstart', function (e) {
      e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'copy';
      e.dataTransfer.setData('Text', this.id);
    });
  }


  // give products drop events
  var products = document.querySelectorAll('li.product'), thisProduct = null;
  for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
    thisProduct = products[i];

    addEvent(thisProduct, 'dragover', function (e) {
      if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();
      this.className = 'product_over';
      e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy';
      return false;
    });

    addEvent(thisProduct, 'dragleave', function () {
     this.className = 'product';
    });

    addEvent(thisProduct, 'drop', function (e) {
      //alert(thisProduct.id);
      if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
      var thisItem = document.getElementById(e.dataTransfer.getData('Text'));
      thisItem.parentNode.removeChild(thisItem);
      thisProduct.className = 'product';
      handleDrop(thisItem, thisProduct);
      return false;
    });

  }

  // handle the drop
  function handleDrop(i, p) {
    alert(i.id + ' to ' + p.id);
    var done = document.querySelector('#done > ul');
    done.appendChild(i);
    i.className = 'listitem_done';
  } 


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is why it's often a bad idea to define functions (such as callback functions) within a loop. You're assigning `thisProduct` within the loop, but it will be reassigned for the next iteration of the loop. The way your closures are set up, each callback is bound to the same variable `thisProduct`, and will use the latest value.

One possible fix is to create a new closure where `thisProduct` is needed such as

```
(function(thisProduct) {
    addEvent(thisProduct, 'drop', function (e) {
      //alert(thisProduct.id);
      if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
      var thisItem = document.getElementById(e.dataTransfer.getData('Text'));
      thisItem.parentNode.removeChild(thisItem);
      thisProduct.className = 'product';
      handleDrop(thisItem, thisProduct);
      return false;
    });
}(thisProduct));
```

This [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NsxNf/) seems to work for me now. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops.3a_A_common_mistake) for more explanation.

Comment: Thanks!  That makes sense then why the last id was always appearing.  The MDN link was helpful; it seems I have a bit to learn about closures.