# HTML5 multiple drop targets defined in loop

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

This seems like a similar problem as is found here, but I'm afraid I'm not understanding the solution provided.  [Multiple drop events in HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6717853/multiple-drop-events-in-html5)

I'm attempting to setup multiple drop targets from one drag source, using the Ext JS library.  When I define the closure for notifyEnter, it appears as if it will always use the variable "i", to alert (I've changed it to alert for debugging purposes).  Coming from a Java background, my gut is to solve this by defining a final variable within the loop and assigning either i or the playerLocationPanel that I'd like to it before defining the closure, but that doesn't appear to be a valid solution.

This is my first foray into Javascript in 8-10 years, so your help is greatly appreciated.

```
/****
* Setup Drop Targets
***/
var playerPanelDropTargets = new Array();
var dropTargetEls = new Array();
for(var i=0;i<=5; i++){
    dropTargetEls[i] = playerLocationPanels[i].body.dom;

    playerPanelDropTargets[i] = Ext.create('Ext.dd.DropTarget', dropTargetEls[i], {
        ddGroup: 'GridExample',
        notifyEnter: function(ddSource, e, date){
            // The problem here is that it always calls, specifically playerLocationPanels[i]
            // and i is always going to be 1 more than the top of the loop.
            //playerLocationPanels[i].body.stopAnimation();
            //playerLocationPanels[i].body.highlight();
            alert(i);

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take the same basic approach as mentioned in that question you reference: your "notifyEnter" function needs to be created in a separate function to which you pass "i", and which returns the handler function.  Something like this:

```
playerPanelDropTargets[i] = Ext.create('Ext.dd.DropTarget', dropTargetEls[i], {
    ddGroup: 'GridExample',
    notifyEnter: makeHandler(i)
});

// ...

function makeHandler(i) {
  return function(ddSource, e, date){
        alert(i);
        // etc.
    };
}
```

By calling another function to create the handler function, you ensure that each handler function has its own copy of the value of "i".

Comment: That makes it perfectly clear.  It's been a while since I've used closures.  Thanks for the help.